# Duality of linear programs without non-negativity constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

It seems that every theory of duality I can find in the theory of linear programs employs the fact that the variables $x_i$ in the program are non-negative. Is there a theory of duality, giving us the complementary slackness property, etc, where the variables of a linear program are not necessarily non-negative, but instead can take on unbounded real values?

Comment: There is a general dual problem construction that applies to any convex optimization problem with inequality and equality constraints. You should definitely learn it. The construction (and KKT conditions) are discussed in Boyd and Vandenberghe, for example. The book is free online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can find the dual of an LP in which variables have general upper and lower bounds, some of which might be $\pm \infty$.  This is discussed in many textbooks on linear programming.

Note that if all of the variables are free (no upper or lower bounds) than either the LP is infeasible, the LP is unbounded or all feasible solutions have the same objective value.  The dual of such an LP is of very little interest.

To see this, consider the linear system of equations $Ax=b$.  Either

1. There is a unique solution to $Ax=b$, which is obviously optimal (but not very interesting.) In this case, all feasible solutions have the same objective value.

or

2. There are no solutions to $Ax=b$, and the LP is infeasible.

or

3. There are infinitely many solutions to $Ax=b$ which form an affine set (some sort of hyperplane in $R^{n}$.  Then either

3.a. The vector $c$ is orthogonal to hyperplane of feasible solutions, in which case every solution to the LP has the same (optimal) objective value.

or

3.b. The vector $c$ is not orthogonal to the hyperplane of feasible solutions, in which case the LP is unbounded.

Comment: `if all of the variables are free (no upper or lower bounds) than either the LP is infeasible, the LP is unbounded or all feasible solutions have the same objective value`.  This sounds very strange.

Comment: See my expanded answer above.  Basically, you have to have inequalities of some sort in the LP formulation or it will be very uninteresting.

Comment: Sorry, I read this as "no bounds", not as "no inequalities".

Comment: The answer assumes that you're solving an LP formulated with equality constraints and variabiles that can have upper and/or lower bounds or be free.  All inequality constraints would first be rewritten with slack variables to get into this form.

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply the general dual problem construction to the LP
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \langle c, x \rangle \\
\text{subject to} & \quad Ax = b, \\
& \quad Cx \leq d.
\end{align}
The Lagrangian is
\begin{align}
L(x,z,w)
&= \langle c, x \rangle + \langle z,Ax - b \rangle + \langle w, Cx - d \rangle \\
&= \langle c + A^T z + C^T w, x \rangle - \langle z,b \rangle - \langle w, d \rangle.
\end{align}
The dual function is
\begin{align}
G(z,w) &= \inf_x L(x,z,w) \\
&= \begin{cases} -\langle z,b \rangle - \langle w,d \rangle \quad \text{if } c + A^T z + C^T w = 0, \\
-\infty \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
The dual problem is
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}_{z,w} & \quad - \langle z,b \rangle - \langle w, d \rangle \\
\text{subject to} & \quad c + A^T z + C^T w = 0,\\
& \quad w \geq 0.
\end{align}
The KKT conditions are:
\begin{align}
Ax &= b ,\\
Cx & \leq d, \\
c + A^T z + C^T w &= 0, \\
w &\geq 0, \\
w_i(Cx - d)_i &= 0 \quad \text{for all }i.
\end{align}